# Text area value not getting inserted into MYSQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I am trying to store the shipping address of the customer into my mysql database. The code is being executed but the value is not being stored.

The method is being called but the row isnt being updated in mysql database.

Can anyone please help me with it ?

```
<?php
    /* connecting to my database */
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'test');
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        echo "Database connection failed with following errors" . mysqli_connect_error();
        die();
        /* Error handling */
    }
    /* Button pressed  */

    if ($_POST['buy']) {
        /* Post variable */
        $text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adress']);
        /* Executing query */
        $query = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO `test` `shipping` (`id`, `adress`, `product`) VALUES (NULL, 'hghghghghgh', '')");
    }
?>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"> </div>
        // Product info //
        <form action="iphone.php" method="post">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">#6</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <img src="images/iphone.jpg" width="300px" height="250px" align="center">
                        <p>iPhone 6S </p>
                        <p class="price" name="price"> Total Price : 68,999/-</p>
                        <p><span  style="color:blue">Mode of payment</span> <span   style="color: green" > : Cash On Delivery </span></p>
                        <p class="price" name="price"> Shipping Adress </p>
                        <input type="textarea"  id="adress" name="adress" style="width:350px; height:200px"/>
                        <br /> <br />
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="buy" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#details-6">Buy now</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: "INSERT INTO `test` `shipping`  whats this ?

Comment: You are mixing mysql and mysqli

Comment: if `id` is auto incremented than no need to insert this

Comment: @SriTeja : At least respond to answer given below.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, the code works after trying what you have said. Sorry for late response.

Comment: Hi @SriTejaChilakamarri :  *Glad To Hear.* Please tick my answer as correct answer. As, it will help other user to find it easily. And, if you don't have idea how to mark answer as correct answer. Then, Please have a look http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Changes Need to be done.**

**1)** Change

```
if ($_POST['buy']) {
```

To

```
if ($_POST['submit']) {
```

**2)** Change

```
$text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adress']);
```

To

```
$text = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['adress']);
```

**3)** Change

Here, put dot (.) between `test` & `shipping`.

```
$query = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO `test` `shipping` (`id`, `adress`, `product`) VALUES (NULL, 'hghghghghgh', '')");
```

To

```
$query = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO `test`.`shipping` (`id`, `adress`, `product`) VALUES (NULL, 'hghghghghgh', '')");
```

**Updated Code**

```
<?php

    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'test');
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        echo "Database connection failed with following errors" . mysqli_connect_error();
        die();
    }


    if ($_POST['submit']) {
        $text = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['adress']);
        $query = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO `test`.`shipping` (`id`, `adress`, `product`) VALUES ('', 'hghghghghgh', '')");
    }
?>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2"> </div>
    // Product info //
    <form action="iphone.php" method="post">
          <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">#6</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
              <img src="images/iphone.jpg" width="300px" height="250px" align="center">
              <p>iPhone 6S </p>
              <p class="price" name="price"> Total Price : 68,999/-</p>
              <p><span  style="color:blue">Mode of payment</span> <span   style="color: green" > : Cash On Delivery </span></p>
              <p class="price" name="price"> Shipping Adress </p>
              <input type="textarea"  id="adress" name="adress" style="width:350px; height:200px"/>
              <br /> <br />
              <button type="submit" name="submit" value="buy" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#details-6">Buy now</button>
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>
    </form>
</div>
```